# dtls handshake failed with alert decrypt error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, openssl, handshake, dtls

I'm implementing a dtls-srtp handshake from client (openssl with VS C++), but it failed. The message flow on wireshark turned out like this:

- Client Hello
- Server Hello, Certificate (Fragment), Certificate (Fragment), Certificate (Fragment), Certificate (Reassembled), Certificate Request, Server Hello Done
- Certificate (Fragment), Certificate (Fragment), Certificate (Fragment), Certificate (Reassembled), Client Key Exchange, Certificate Verify (Fragment)
- Server Hello, Certificate[Reassembly error, protocol DTLS: New fragment overlaps old data (retransmission?)]
- Client Hello
- Server Hello, Certificate[Reassembly error, protocol DTLS: New fragment overlaps old data (retransmission?)]
- Client Hello, Certificate[Reassembly error, protocol DTLS: New fragment overlaps old data (retransmission?)]
- Server Hello, Certificate[Reassembly error, protocol DTLS: New fragment overlaps old data (retransmission?)]
- Certificate Verify (Reassembled), Change Cipher Spec, Certificate[Reassembly error, protocol DTLS: New fragment overlaps old data (retransmission?)]
- Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Decrypt Error)

Does anyone has any idea what's going on here? Is it the problem of certificate/key, or did I miss any SSL option / parameter?

I tried to change the mtu value but it didn't work.

Modified: logs from client

> *SSL_CB_HANDSHAKE_START unknown: before/connect initialization
>
> SSL_CB_LOOP SSL_connect: before/connect initialization
>
> SSL_CB_LOOP SSL_connect: SSLv3 write client hello A
>
> SSL_CB_EXIT SSL_connect: SSLv3 read server hello A
>
> SSL_CB_EXIT SSL_connect: SSLv3 read server hello A
>
> -> connect err=-1 errRet=SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ
>
> SSL_CB_LOOP SSL_connect: SSLv3 read server hello A
>
> SSL_CB_LOOP SSL_connect: SSLv3 read server certificate A
>
> SSL_CB_LOOP SSL_connect: SSLv3 read server certificate request A
>
> SSL_CB_LOOP SSL_connect: SSLv3 read server done A
>
> SSL_CB_LOOP SSL_connect: SSLv3 write client certificate A
>
> SSL_CB_LOOP SSL_connect: SSLv3 write client key exchange A
>
> SSL_CB_LOOP SSL_connect: SSLv3 write certificate verify A
>
> SSL_CB_EXIT SSL_connect: error
>
> -> connect err=-1 errRet=SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL*

Comment: [RFC6347 - Figure 1. Message Flights for Full Handshake][1]

According that, you reach flight 5, but it ends with "Certificate Verify (Fragment)".
I'm wondering, why that message got fragmented (it only has a couple of bytes). The flight 5 must contain CCS and FINISH, but these are missing. Did openssl wrote something to the logs/console?

  [1]: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6347#page-20

Comment: I added the logs from client. Btw, Certificate Verify is expected to have length of 142 bytes, for it contains a signature with 128b length.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have deep openssl knowledge ;-(, so I have no detail information about the error cause. Sorry.

Comment: Have you fixed the problem? I have met a similar one now.